# Tomcat and IIS6 on one server, multiple websites

Tags: iis-6, tomcat

Windows Server 2003 with IIS6 and Tomcat 6.0.26.

Three sites running on this server. One is PHP, one is ASP and the third uses Tomcat. The first two work flawlessly. The third is being a pain.

Tomcat is installed and if called on the server itself by IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 shows the welcome page. Calling the same address from an external machine gives a 'could not connect' error. Calling the ip address from within the server on standard port 80 gives me an error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE).

Have tried using httpcfg to force listening only on ports within the ip range I'm using in a manner similar to question 35650 located here on serverfault but with no success. There are actually ten ip addresses on this machine but I'm only using three of them at this point.

Any pointers on troubleshooting this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using port 8080 works on the server, but not externally, I would first look at any firewall set up blocking other than the standard port (80).

Comment: Ah, a silly oversight on my part. What wonders will happen when the correct ports are open! That is to say - it worked! That being said, I'm still getting the same error as above when I try to access the site via port 80. Something is still amiss.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling II6's socket pooling feature, so that it only listens on what you tell it to, instead of all IP addresses by default:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238131